# Remove # from start of word using regex

Tags: python, regex

Using regex, is there a way to remove the # sign at the start of all words in a string ? It only needs to be removed from the start.

For example `This #is a #test string` should be transformed into `This is a test string`

I'm new to regex so still learning.

EDIT:

I tried the following but it doesn't work:

`print re.sub(r'#\w+', r'\w+', "#hello")` ... it changes `#hello` to `w+`, whereas it should change it to `hello`

Comment: So what have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: Do you mean to remove all hashes, or only hashes _at the beginning of words_?

Comment: Yes I did try on my own. I've posted a snippet above. I can identify what needs to be replaced, however my regex for the replacement string is wrong somehow.

Comment: Only remove from the beginning

Comment: I thought regex was for extracting text, not replacing. Only the first parameter to `re.sub` is a regex, the second is a string literal, as you've discovered.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the string method replace():

```
In [1]: s = 'This #is a #test string'
In [2]: s = s.replace('#', '')
In [3]: s
Out[3]: 'This is a test string'
```

http://pythoncentral.io/pythons-string-replace-method-replacing-python-strings/

Here is a regex version:

```
In [1]: import re
In [2]: s = 'This #is a #test # string#'
In [3]: pattern = re.compile('#(?=[a-zA-Z0-9])')
In [4]: re.sub(pattern,'', s)
Out[4]: 'This is a test # string#'
```

Comment: I think you missed the part of the question that said. "It only needs to be removed from the start."

Comment: @cricket_007: Indeed

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the whitespace and the word you want to keep into groups, and use back references to keep them;

```
print re.sub(r'(^|\s+)#(\w+)', r'\1\2', '#This #is a #test stri#ng')         
# This is a test stri#ng
```

`(^|\s+)` matches whitespaces or start of the row.
`#`matches the hash you want removed.
`(\w+)` matches the word.

The replace string uses two back references `\1\2`, one for the whitespace, one for the word, but leaving out the hash.

Comment: That works, thanks! Also thanks for the explanation !

Comment: Actually, you made the character following the hashtag the group, not the whole word

Comment: @cricket_007 Whoops, fixed.

Comment: This regex can be further simplified as: `(^|\s+)#(\w+)`, then replace with `\1\2`.